# In Android how to convert Facebook and Twitter posts date into same fomat?

Tags: java, android

I have two date one is from facebook and second is from twitter how can i convert them into same format.
Below are the dates which I am getting

Facebook Date= 2012-07-05T13:17:13+0000
Twitter Date= Thu Jul 05 22:15:04 GMT+05:30 2012

How can we convert both of two like: 05-Jul-2012 11:54:30 
please help me to solve this out..
Thanks

Comment: What date libs are you using?  JODA?

Comment: I am working on it but not getting which method provide the exact wanted date.

Answer (score 0):

The [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) should help out a lot here.

You'll want to create two of them, one for each date format.  Then you can use the `parse()` method to turn those into `Date` objects.

Finally, you can use the `format()` method to turn them back into strings if you desire.

Also, this is using Java time, which is less preferrable than JODA time, but it might work for you purposes.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are working for convert facebook and twitter date to your preferred format.

**Function for convert Facebook Date :**

```
String old_date="2012-07-05T13:17:13+0000";

private String Convert_Facebook_Date(String old_date) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat old = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

            Date date = null;
            try {

                date = old.parse(old_date); 

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }

        return sdf.format(date);        
}
```

**Function for convert Twitter Date :**

```
String old_date="Thu Jul 05 22:15:04 GMT+05:30 2012";

private String Convert_Twitter_Date(String old_date) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat old = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
        old.setLenient(true);

            Date date = null;
            try {

                date = old.parse(old_date);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return sdf.format(date);    
}
```

> The both output format like :  05-Jul-2012 11:54:30